# Power BI: Use dim table in conditional formatting as criteria, keeping one measure instead of multiple

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following structure of tables:
fact_Phone (* < 1) Dim_Users (* <> 1) Dim_user_ID

- The fact_Phone table have usernames. *This is many to one, single direction to dim_users*
- The dim_users have the username and proper name but not the ID. *This is many to one in both directions to dim_user ID*
- The dim_user_ID have proper name, user ID and country.

I figured out how to check ***if the handling times of the calls are on target or not***, although I had to separate the handling times into two different measures first, leading to the need of two columns. This is not wanted, and I cannot figure out how to merge them into one measure, while still checking for my country condition from my dim_user_ID table.. any ideas?

In my Matrix, I use dim_user_ID[country] as my rows with the dim_user_ID[name] as the secondary row, and then I tried to use my calculated measures to show the average handling times. ***So far, so good.*** *..except that they are in different columns.*

This is what I have tried so far, although that means I have to have two measures, ultimately forcing me to have two columns (one for each country, which is not wanted):

```
AHT (Phone NO) = DIVIDE(
                        SUMX(
                            FILTER(
                               fact_Phone,
                               RELATED(dim_user_ID[country])="NO"
                            ), fact_Phone[Total AHT]
                        ),
                        SUMX(
                            FILTER(
                                fact_Phone,
                                RELATED(dim_user_ID[country])="NO"
                            ), fact_Phone[Total calls answered]
                        )
                    )


AHT (Phone SE) = DIVIDE(
                        SUMX(
                            FILTER(
                               fact_Phone,
                               RELATED(dim_user_ID[country])="SE"
                            ), fact_Phone[Total AHT]
                        ),
                        SUMX(
                            FILTER(
                                fact_Phone,
                                RELATED(dim_user_ID[country])="SE"
                            ), fact_Phone[Total calls answered]
                        )
                    )
```

Then based on this one, I create one new measure that can be used for the conditional formatting:

```
Check AHT on target = 
IF(
    '1 Measures'[AHT (Phone NO)] > 240
        || '1 Measures'[AHT (Phone SE)] > 260,
    0,
    1
)
```

---

**Solved:**
Kept the two measures above, and changed the last measure to this:

```
Check AHT on target = 
    IF(
        NOT(ISBLANK('1 Measures'[AHT (Phone NO)]))
            || NOT(ISBLANK('1 Measures'[AHT (Phone SE)])),
    IF(
       '1 Measures'[AHT (Phone NO)] > 240
            || '1 Measures'[AHT (Phone SE)] > 260,
        0,
        1
))
```

Then it worked to us this measure as the "What field should we base this on?" in the conditional formatting for a simpler AHT measure:

```
AHT (Phone) = DIVIDE(SUM(fact_Phone[Total AHT]),SUM(fact_Phone[Total calls answered]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. I only had to create the to measures AHT (Phone NO) and AHT (Phone SE), then I could use the "Check AHT on target" measure on one simpler measure being ´`AHT (Phone) = DIVIDE(SUM(fact_Phone[Total AHT]),SUM(fact_Phone[Total calls answered]))` ..now I just need to figure out how to return nothing if the AHT for the specific measures result in blanks.. and I will mark this as the answer later, I have to wait two days though.